Is it possible to put repetitive code logic into a separate function in createAsyncThunk (Redux Toolkit)?
I have an application structure. Example:

entities/user/services/checkAuth
features/auth-user/services/login (registration, logout, refresh)

Examples of service (1):
export const refreshService = createAsyncThunk<void>(
    'auth-user/refreshService',
    async (_, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<AuthResponse>('http://localhost:4000/api/refresh', { withCredentials: true })
            const { tokens, user } = response.data

            thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.setData(user))
            thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.authorize())
            localStorage.setItem(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, tokens.accessToken)
        }
        catch (error) {
            ...
        }
    },
)


Examples of service (2):
export const refreshService = createAsyncThunk<UserEntity, RegistrationRequest>(
    'auth-user/registrationService',
    async (data, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post<AuthResponse>('http://localhost:4000/api/registration', data)

            if (!response.data) {
                throw new Error()
            }

            const { user, tokens } = response.data

            thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.setData(user))
            thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.authorize())
            localStorage.setItem(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, tokens.accessToken)

            return user
        }
        catch (error) {
            ...
        }
    },
)

In many of them this code section is repeated:
thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.setData(user))
thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.authorize())
localStorage.setItem(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, tokens.accessToken)

Is there a way to reuse this functionality in the Redux Toolkit?

Sure, you can almost always factor out commonly used/repeated code into utility functions. Surely you'd need more than just those three lines of code to be repeated though (unless you are saying that several of your thunks call an API that returns token and user values). Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] demonstrating the duplicate code that you are wanting to make more DRY?

@DrewReese I added another service for an example. They are similar, but the request method (POST, GET) and URL are changed. I would like to put the code responsible for dispatch and local storage in a separate function.  I realize that these three lines are not that big, but in the future I would like to understand how it can be solved. The only way I can think of is to create a function that takes thunkAPI, user, tokens as arguments and performs the dispatch within it

"The only way I can think of is to create a function that takes thunkAPI, user, tokens as arguments and performs the dispatch within it" - That is exactly it.  A slight variation on this would/could be to create another Thunk (that has access to the store/ThunkAPI) so you'd only need to pass user and token.

@DrewReese Great, I just thought there was some special way for Redux. Thanks a lot

I tried putting the code in a separate function and it seems to work:
export const handleAuthResponse = (
    thunkAPI: GetThunkAPI<AsyncThunkConfig>,
    user: UserEntity,
    tokens: TokenEntity,
) => {
    thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.setData(user))
    thunkAPI.dispatch(userActions.authorize())
    localStorage.setItem(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, tokens.accessToken)
}

Usage:
try {
    const response = await axios.get<AuthResponse>('http://localhost:4000/api/refresh', {
                withCredentials: true,
     })

    const { user, tokens } = response.data

    handleAuthResponse(thunkAPI, user, tokens)
 }

